# Cannot link the react code to html successful

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to embed a react code to my html file, but I have some problem with that.

My code is:

```
<div class="four wide column">
        <div id="Eva"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
          import React, { Component } from "react";
          import { Card, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
          import EvaImage from "../src/Image/eva.png";

          var CardExampleCardProps = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
              return (
                <Card
                  image={EvaImage}
                  header="Elliot Baker"
                  meta="Friend"
                  description="Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat."
                  extra={extra}
                />
              );
            }
          });
          const EvaId = document.getElementById("Eva");
          React.render(<CardExampleCardProps />, EvaId);
        </script>
</div>
```

And I link the CDN here:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
```

There is no error in the browser console. Anyone knows what happened here?

Comment: This is how CRA 2.0 insert the app into the div container `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));` so you can try `ReactDOM.render(<CardExampleCardProps />, document.getElementById('Eva'));`

Comment: @Drusto Thank you for your time! Mind if I ask what is CRA 2.0?

Comment: here is the code I wrote on codesandbox `https://codesandbox.io/s/addreacttoweb-pqvtw` Seems like not working neither

Comment: CRA 2.0 is Create React App command used to create a react app from scratch

Comment: Got it. I do not know why. This code is really messy and is not working

Comment: I have not used react as a simple script in an html static webpage. How it is supposed to work?           import { Card, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";      I think you will need to download or install that package, as a normal react app do in package.json

Comment: In codesandbox, you can add dependencies which I already did . I think import is okay because that is what normal react will do (it is in the <script> tag)

Comment: I think you need to use https://cdnjs.com/libraries/require.js/ require instead of import.

Answer (score 1):

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hy3tev1c/2/

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="four wide column">
        <div id="Eva"></div>
        <div class="four wide column">
        <div id="Eva"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
          import React, { Component } from "react";
          import { Card, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
          import EvaImage from "../src/Image/eva.png";

          var CardExampleCardProps = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
              return (
                <Card
                  image={EvaImage}
                  header="Elliot Baker"
                  meta="Friend"
                  description="Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat."
                  extra={extra}
                />
              );
            }
          });
          const EvaId = document.getElementById("Eva");
          React.render(<CardExampleCardProps />, EvaId);
        </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```